# signTool gives error not exists for existing file

Tags: signtool

I am using signTool like this:

```
Signtool sign /debug /v /s "Personal" /n www.site.com /t http://timestamp.digicert.com D:\file.exe
```

I have certificate issued by [www.site.com](http://www.site.com) and this file.exe. But it gives me
SignTool Error: File not found:
If I try like this:

```
Signtool sign /debug /v /sm /n www.site.com /t http://timestamp.digicert.com D:\file.exe
```

I have this output:

```
The following certificates were considered:
Issued to: 
Issued by: www.columbo.me
Expires:   Sun Oct 27 00:00:00 2024
SHA1 hash: 242E4B72FB3E67417DD2C8FCC3A12084F73B18EA

After EKU filter, 1 certs were left.
After expiry filter, 1 certs were left.
After Subject Name filter, 0 certs were left.
After Private Key filter, 0 certs were left.
```

SignTool Error: No certificates were found that met all the given criteria.

What am I doing wrong

Comment: Why don't you remove `/sm` option?

Comment: So from the debug there is only one certificate available for code signing. I suspect if your certificate has been issued to www.site.com  then its possible an ssl certificate and not a code signing certificate. If open the certificate store as local machine or the user, where ever the cert, has been installed open the properties and on the general tab check Code Signing is included.